# Using very with picky

Tags: word-usage

"We need to do this in a better way because the manager is very picky about quality"
Although this sentence does seem grammatically correct to me. But is it ok to add **very** with picky? Because picky already means very careful. Or is there a different word one can use for **very picky**

Comment: Could picky be thought of or used as a metaphor too in a sentence? It does seem to have a figurative meaning

Answer (score 2):

I would not replace picky with "very careful", it often (not always) has a bit of a negative conotation.

It can mean *selective* as in "tending to select carefully" or *choosy* as in "hard to please".

In your example I would translate it as "the manager is hard to please when it comes to quality" so adding very is perfectly fine: "The manager is very hard to please when it comes to quality."

Comment: I would spell 'choosy' thus.

Comment: "Careful" might suggest that the manager is very conscientious in their own work, while "picky" or "choosy" suggests an attitude to other people's work.

Comment: I have seen both version, but the dictionary clearly says choosy. Thank you @MichaelHarvey . Amended.

Comment: You never really explain why the "negative connotation" makes "very careful" a bad translation. After all, [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/picky) includes "very careful" in its definition of "choosy", and perhaps OP wants a negative connotation.